# using \'Geocodable address\' in ST_INTERSECTS

Tags: javascript, google-fusion-tables

I am trying to use the ST_INTERSECTS in my where clause, which is based off of the examples: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/circle_example

However, my maps query uses the \'Geocodable address\' in the select statement:

select: '\'Geocodable address\'',
      from: '1Kbk6De...........hwQoEsOIHb'

and that works fine until I add the where clause:

var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: '\'Geocodable address\'',
      from: '1Kbk6DeAEB61............QoEsOIHb',
      where:  'ST_INTERSECTS(\'Geocodable address\', CIRCLE(LATLNG(39.3232, -76.7234),' + meters + '))'
    }

The example uses "address" which is a field they have on their table. I only have latitude and longitude points on my table, and no actual field exists called Geocodable address.  I am assuming this is derived from some sort of fusion api code from the interpretation of the fusion table data I imported?

Is there a way to get it working using this 'Geocodable address' column?  I also have columns called latitude and longitude that have this data if that is usable.  I have tried using latlng(latitude,longitude) instead of \'Geocodable address\' just the same, with no recognition of the boundaries.  I just want to only show the data inside the circle when it's drawn and it ends up showing all of the table data instead.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

See this [forum post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/fusion-tables-users-group/nKmmS6x_KOw/mfg8d0cXNHIJ); you can use the first of the columns specified for a two-column lat/lng.

Comment: Please don't just link to an external resource, include enough information from that link so that your answer will still be useful if the link wasn't there.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I had, it was more of for a reference if it turns out I was more confusing than helpful with the information presented below.  I can refrain from putting a link questions.  Rod - your answer was spot on!

Comment: The comment was directed at @Rod McChesney

Comment: @geocodezip: The second half of my post is the gist of the forum post, so I thought that was sufficient to answer the question.